# Do planets experience coriolis effect in terms of rotation around a star?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, coriolis-effect

We all know from General Relativity theory that movement of objects around, for example, a star actually straight in spacetime continuum. It just time distortion causes the movement to curve.

Considering this, I have the following questions:

1. Do planets experience coriolis effect in terms of rotation around a
   star?
2. And do I correctly understand that space distortion happens only in
   time dimension?

Comment: It is not just time distortion that causes the object to move in a curve. It is certainly true that is is mostly the curvature associated with the time coordinate because the time component of the 4 velocity is usually the largest, but all the curvature terms (the _Christoffel symbols_) affect the motion. So your question is based on a false premise. For more on this see [Why does mass bend the temporal dimension more than the spatial dimensions of spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/684074/why-does-mass-bend-the-temporal-dimension-more-than-the-spatial-dimensions-of-sp).

Comment: @JohnRennie Your comment addresses a different issue - but it made me think - is there a tensor-based derivation of the Coriolis pseudforce, or is it as simple as substracting the frame motion into the centrifugal term?

Comment: There is a possible way to think about this, which may help: if the orbit is near circular, you can imagine the planet being attached to a rotating disc which just happens to rotate at the same speed. Clearly, there are Coriolis effects on this disc. Now, since our planet is supposedly not a point mass but has some area along the plane of the orbit, the Coriolis effect of our entire imaginary disc will extend to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the force is Coriolis or centrifugal, or if the planet accelerates radially is frame dependent. For mass $m$ planet *revolving* at speed $v$ in a radius of $R$:

In an inertial frame, there are no fictitious forces, and the centripetal force caused by gravity is:

$$ F_g = \frac{mv^2} R $$

which keeps the planet in orbit

In a rotating frame ($\omega=v/R$) in which the planet is fixed, there is a centrifugal force:

$$ F_{cent} = {m\omega^2}R = {m(v/R)^2}R = \frac{mv^2}R = F_g$$

Since the planet is stationary, there is no Coriolis force. The total fictitious force balances gravity, and the planet remains fixed.

In a frame moving at $\omega'=\omega/2$, there is a centrifugal force:

$$  F'_{cent} = \frac{m\omega'^2} R = \frac{mv^2}{4R}  $$

In this frame, the planet's velocity is:

$$ v' = v - R\omega' = v-v/2 = v/2 $$

The Coriolis force is:

$$ F'_{cor} = 2m\omega' v' = 2m(v'/R)v' = \frac{mv^2}{2R}$$

which is in the anti-radial direction (see Eötvös effect, in while the motion is manifest as a change local gravity).

The total fictitious force is:

$$ F'_{fact} = F'_{cor} + F'_{cent} = \frac 3 4 F_g $$

Hence,the planet experiences a radial force:

$$ \frac 1 4 F_g = \frac{mv'^2} {R} $$

which keeps it on its orbit.

The latter analysis holds for any $\omega'$.