# Reference for list of the non-zero, unique components of the Riemann tensor for the Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, curvature, kerr-metric

Does there exist textbook or webpage which has a list of the unique components of $R^{\mu}_{\nu \alpha \beta}$ for the Kerr metric?

Such a reference is easy enough to find for Schwarzchild ([including on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295814/)), but Kerr is a bit more tricky.

Of course, you can use your favourite symbolic manipulation tool e.g. Mathematica to compute the terms but:

- It is hard to get it into a "nice" form using common symbols in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates such as $\Sigma(r,\theta)$, $\Delta(r)$, etc.
- Mistakes and typos are all to easy to make - would be good to have a de facto "source of truth".

Comment: Check chapter 6 (The Kerr metric) from "The mathematical theory of black holes" by S. Chandrasekhar